# An example of a function $f$ for which there does not exist a sequence of continuous functions $f_n$ converging pointwise to $f$.

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to find a function $f$ for which there does not exist a sequence of continuous functions $f_n$ converging pointwise to $f$.

I would be interested to see some examples. My first idea was the classic "very discontinuous functon" which is $0$ at each rational and $1$ at each irrational, but I believe it is possible to construct such a sequence $f_n$ because the rationals are countable. So I'm rather stuck. Maybe I need to find a subset of $\mathbb R$ which is dense, uncountable and not cocountable? In any case I would struggle to come up with a proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f$ is the pointwise limit of continuous functions, then $f$ has to be continuous in a dense $G_\delta$. (For a proof see [Elementary Real Analysis](http://classicalrealanalysis.info/documents/TBB-AllChapters-Landscape.pdf) by Thomson, Bruckner & Bruckner, page 587.)

Hence
$$
f(x)=\left\{
\begin{array}{lll}
1 & \text{if} & \text{$x\,\,$ rational}, \\
0 & \text{if} & \text{$x\,\,$ irrational},
\end{array}
\right.
$$
can not be the pointwise limit of continuous functions, as $f$ is everywhere discontinuous.

Comment: Why must it be continuous in a dense G_delta?

Comment: See my edited answer. A proof is available in the internet in the book I cite.

Comment: Yiorgos.I am familiar with with the statement if $f_n \rightarrow f$ uniformly, $f_n$ continuos , then $f$ continuos.Was not aware that pointwise convergence (only) is sufficient.Please comment. Thanks, Peter

Comment: The pointwise limit is continuous only in a dense $G_\delta$. Not necessarily everywhere!